# How can i get path without base href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Base assigned in html like this:

```
<base href="http://root/tempop/panel/"/>
```

Current browser URL is:

```
http://root/tempop/panel/about/1
```

And i want this:

```
 about/1
```

How can i get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var endPiece = document.location.href.split('http://root/tempop/panel/')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var base = $("base").prop("href");
var fullurl = "http://root/tempop/panel/about/1"
var path = fullurl.replace(base,"");
console.log(path)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57gbetwp/